# Setting default nice value for a program on linux

Tags: linux, firefox, nice, defaults, process-priority

Strange as it seems, I can't find information how I can set a default nice value for a program (not for a user or a group!). I would like to start all chrome and firefox instances with a nice value of 10. What would be the most appropriate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of messing up your `/usr/bin` and getting hosed every update, why not use a `~/.local/bin` ?

```
## one-time setup
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
# prepend new path to PATH to give it priority
echo 'PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
# then open new terminal or
source ~/.bashrc

## create a wrapper script
# $@ is there to passthrough args.
echo 'nice -10' `which firefox` '$@' > ~/.local/bin/firefox
# make it executable
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/firefox

# check sanity
which firefox
cat `which firefox`
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to work around a bit.

First get the full path of the `firefox` binary:

```
which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Now, move that to, for example, `firefox-original`:

```
mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-original
```

Now, create a small handler script called `/usr/bin/firefox` that will be called instead of the original firefox binary:

```
cat /usr/bin/firefox
#!/bin/bash

exec nice -n 10 /usr/bin/firefox-original "$@"
```

Finally make the script executable:

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/firefox
```

Now every time Firefox is started, that script executes the binary with a nice value of 10. The `$@` just means to pass all the arguments of the script to the binary.

Comment: This should work. But what happens when I upgrade my firefox package (deb in my case)?

Comment: Yes, thats the problem you have to write the script again in that case, it doesn't survive a package update.

Comment: @helcim another attempt whould be to edit the file `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`: the `Exec=` line. But that only works when you start firefox in a gui. That whould survive an update.

Comment: @helcim: For Debian (and derivatives), you should use `dpkg-divert` to have the package manager put the packaged version elsewhere.

Comment: "put elsewhere" is probably not what I want. I would like to set default nice value for a program once AND be able to upgrade as usual.

Comment: @CameronKerr Good point, didn't think of that. It could be made by `dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /usr/bin/firefox --divert /usr/bin/firefox-original`. Then the package software places all new versions of the file to /usr/bin/firefox-original, so the problem of an update would be solved.

Comment: @chaos I see. It seems like the right solution, although I really hate to mess up with the package system more than it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: Unless firefox/chrome themselves don't provide configuration options to define a nice value, then unfortunately you have to do it that way.

Answer (score -2):

Create a keyboard short-cut that will execute the following command:

```
nohup firefox & renice +15 $(pgrep firefox)
```

This should work regardless of whether you upgrade.